# Java and R (JRI) in mixed mode on windows

Tags: java, r

i have followed this  : [Setting up Java R Interface (JRI) on Windows

][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974392/setting-up-java-r-interface-jri-on-windows)

After setting up environment , I have done :

```
public void myFirstExampleWithR() {
    Rengine re=new Rengine();
    System.out.println("yesss");
    REXP x;
    re.eval("print(1:10/3)");
    System.out.println(x=re.eval("iris"));
    RVector v = x.asVector();
    if (v.getNames()!=null) {
        System.out.println("has names:");
        for (Enumeration e = v.getNames().elements() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
            System.out.println(e.nextElement());
        }
    }

    if (true) {
        System.out.println("Now the console is yours ... have fun");
        re.startMainLoop();
    } else {
        re.end();
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, i get :

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\library\rJava\jri\x64
Yesss
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006c819312, 
pid=1828, tid=0x0000000000001ebc
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 
1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode windows-
amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [R.dll+0x119312]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client 
versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\username\service-repository\hs_err_pid1828.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I have update the R version , but still the same stacktrace.
the 'vhs_err_pid1828.log' file didn't help...
What the matter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well no-argument constructor was the issue.. Using constructor with arguments solved my issue:

```
 Rengine re=new Rengine(new String[]{"init"},false,null);
```