# JRI program terminates java during REngine creation

Tags: r, rjava, rserve, jri, rcaller

I want to call an R script using Java. I am trying the JRI method to call the R script. However my JVM gets terminated when creating an Rengine.

I am running one of the examples which has been provided alongside rJava library installation in R.

Code I have tried

Version 1:

```
`Rengine re=new Rengine(args, true, new TextConsole2());`
```

Version 2:

```
`Rengine re=new Rengine(args, false, new TextConsole());`
```

Version 3:

```
`Rengine re = new Rengine(new String[] { "--vanilla" }, false, null);`
```

All three have terminated the JVM while they were getting executed.

I am using STS 3.9.1 and have exposed the below variables before running the Java program
`java.library.path` - pointing to the r java dll's
`R_HOME` - pointing to the R.exe
`PATH` - reinforcing the systems path with the paths of rJava dll's and R.exe

I am using R-3.5.0, followed all steps as per
[Study Trails - R and Java](http://www.studytrails.com/r/r-and-java-jri-using-eclipse/#comment-36621)

and [Mavlarn - R and Java](https://www.cnblogs.com/mavlarn/archive/2012/12/24/2831688.html) but still facing the same issue.
What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: Followed the solution on the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974392/setting-up-java-r-interface-jri-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650780/jri-program-terminates-java-during-rengine-creation)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import org.rosuda.REngine.REngine;

REngine engine = REngine.engineForClass("org.rosuda.REngine.JRI.JRIEngine", new String[] {"-no-save"}, new REngineStdOutput(),false);
```